# AWS DynamoDB Python Connection Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Unable to run sample code on AWS Dynamodb.

I am trying to run the AWS sample python code that they provide on there website. Here is my python file:

```
    from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
    import boto3

   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")


   table = dynamodb.create_table(
       TableName='Movies',
       KeySchema=[
           {
               'AttributeName': 'year',
               'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
           },
           {
               'AttributeName': 'title',
               'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
           }
       ],
       AttributeDefinitions=[
           {
               'AttributeName': 'year',
               'AttributeType': 'N'
           },
           {
               'AttributeName': 'title',
               'AttributeType': 'S'
           },

       ],
       ProvisionedThroughput={
           'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
           'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
       }
   )

   print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

I then I run the python file in terminal and I get the following error:

```
File "MoviesCreateTable.py", line 32, in <module>
    'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 483, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when Dynamodb isn't running. Check `localhost:8000/shell` to verify it's running.

Ensure all the [prerequisites](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.html) given in docs are satisfied.

> Before you begin this tutorial, you need to do the following:
>
> - Download and run DynamoDB on your computer. For more information, see [Download and Run
>     DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JsShell.html#GettingStarted.JsShell.Prereqs.Download).
> - Sign up for Amazon Web Services and create access keys. You need these credentials to use AWS SDKs. To create an AWS account, go to
>     http://aws.amazon.com/, choose Create an AWS Account, and then follow
>     the online instructions.
> - Create an AWS credentials file. For more information, see Configuration in the Boto 3 documentation.
> - Install Python 2.6 or later. For more information, see https://www.python.org/downloads.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How do I actually create a table on AWS instead of my local computer?

Comment: @acsrujan also want to know how to connect aws dynamodb, how to set `endpoint_url`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect cloud instance instead of localhost then refer following region based endpoints.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
```

Comment: Correct answer! this is what helped resolve the issue in my case when I was getting "connection refused" when calling dynamodb from AWS lambda. Needed to replace the endpoint URL from localhost to the correct value from the AWS regional endpoint.